# Hide items in a form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, column, hidden

Recently, I see this function broken in SharePoint, I do not set it.

Please help me.

To begin,

1. Go to List Settings.
2. Click on Advanced Settings.
3. Select Yes on Allow management of content types.
4. Click on one of the existing content types under the Content Type section Next.
5. Click on the column you intend to hide, and choose the option Hidden.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I could not config a function as hiding items in a form of share point. Hope you in my situation.

Comment: What is the data type of column?

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I hide the column in the content type by following your steps.

Then it can hide the column in the forms in modern experience or classic experience.

To troubleshoot the issue, you could create a new column and hide the new column in the forms to check if the same issue will occur.

And then create a new list and check if the same issue will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, by following the steps you provided it should hide the field from list form.

You can also refer the steps from (If anything is missing): [Hiding fields in a SharePoint list](https://diegocampereira.com/2016/12/27/hiding-fields-in-a-sharepoint-list/).

**Note**: If your column type is **Yes/No** then you will not able to hide the field in this way (By design).

Also, if you are using Classic experience then you can hide the fields from list form by using code something like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('nobr:contains("FieldDisplayName")').closest('tr').hide(); '
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, please accept it as an answer.